# Default value of observeChanges in handsontable

Tags: handsontable

The documentation says the default value of observeChanges is false. But it seems to be setting the value to true. Is the default value applicable only when the sort plugin is disabled?

We are the noticing the rendering is invoked multiple times due to this and are wondering if it can be set to false explicitly.

Here is the jsfiddle:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var container = document.getElementById('basic_example');

  var data = function() {
    return Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(10, 10);
  };

  var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: data(),
    colHeaders: true,
    rowHeaders: true,
    stretchH: 'all',
    columnSorting: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });

  if (container.clientHeight < 500) {
    container.height = container.clientHeight;
    hot.updateSettings({
      height: container.clientHeigh
    });
    hot.render();
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    var output = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = hot.getSettings().observeChanges;
  }, 1000);


});
```

```css
</style> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> <link href="http://handsontable.com//styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet"> <link href="http://handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.css" rel="stylesheet"> <script src="http://handsontable.com//bower_components/handsontable/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script> <style type="text/css"> body {
  background: white;
  margin: 20px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}
div#basic_example {
  border: 5px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<span>Default value for observe changes</span>


<div id="basic_example"></div>

<span id="output">Output</span>
```

Click here for jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mpusarla/nva6b8e8/1/

Comment: why are you rendering after calling `updateSettings`? It calls it for you. This will render twice. Not totally related to the oversveChanges attribute but still a bug

Comment: Yep, that's correct. I don't need the render call after updateSettings.

Comment: if you remove it does it still render multiple times?

Comment: Yes, renderer is called multiple times. Here is a simple example:http://jsfiddle.net/mpusarla/z208cw35/

Comment: ok yes it renders twice when making a change, that makes sense since one is for the table and the other for the clone table. What's the issue? You want to turn off the rendering after every change?

Comment: When you run the above jsfiddle, you will see the following output (without any changes) "renderer invoked for 0--0" 3 times. Updating the columnSorting to false in the fiddle will output "renderer invoked for 0--0" 2 times. The ObserveChanges is getting set to true when sorting is enabled and is triggering extra render. Trying to understand if we can explicitly set observeChanges to false to prevent the rendering multiple times.

Comment: I'm not sure about setting `observeChanges` since internally it might be overriding it even if you set it. What I'm saying is that it's not that it renders twice, it's that it renders each table once. There is a "clone" table that takes care of freezing col/rows which is why you're seeing a second render. The initial 3 renders are because it has to render the headers table and the other two tables, I think. What's the use case for this? It' likely you want to be using a different event here.